# how to iterate through a column in resultset javafx

Tags: sql, javafx

say i have this query " select * from lessons" which has a columns named lesson_code and lessons_name.

then i fetch it to a resultset.

then i want to get a value from a textfield then i try to find it in lesson_code column, then another value from textfield but this time i try to find it on lessons_name column

how to iterate through a certain column, or is there another way to do this ?

```
    //some other codes

    //lessons table has lesson_code and lesson_name column
    String query = "select * from lessons";
    ResultSet rset = statement.executeQuery(query);

    //need to find this value in lesson_code if it exists
    code_val = codeTextField.getText();

    //need to find this value in lesson_name if it exists
    name_val = nameTextField.getText();
```

Comment: Please post the code you have tried

Comment: hi, i only have the query and fetch the resulset codes since i tried to google how to do this but got no results.

Comment: you need to store the output of the `ResultSet' into a list first of all. The values from the `TextField` is transferred to the final list on any other control action(Eg. button click) or is there any other way to check at what point of time the value needs to be fetched?